# Access security warning

Tags: security, ms-access, hyperlink, readonly

When i open access i get the warning : Specific content in the database is disabled. I open Access via a link (for a program i use) [http://startprogramma/'C:/Program%20Files/Microsoft%20Office/OFFICE12/MSACCESS.EXE'%20'C:/Users/internet/Documents/Fotos%20Leeuwarderadeel.mdb'](http://startprogramma/%27C:/Program%20Files/Microsoft%20Office/OFFICE12/MSACCESS.EXE%27%20%27C:/Users/internet/Documents/Fotos%20Leeuwarderadeel.mdb%27)

Also the warning of read-only. But i though this is because it gives a security warning.

When i open the link via the program i get the warning. When i just open the file from desktop it doens't give any warning.

Anybody has an idea why this is and how to fix it?

additional info: The location in the link (the documents map) is a trusted location already.

Comment: I suspect you'll find that hyperlink puts a *copy* of the MDB in your temp folder, then opens that MDB copy read-only.  If I'm correct, it doesn't matter that the original MDB location is trusted --- you're not opening it from there --- you're opening a copy instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need write permissions to the directory where the database is opened.